# How to make a open-circuit cable fault detector?

Tags: voltage, current, resistance, voltage-divider

There are projects like this one over here: [Underground Cable Fault Distance Finder](http://nevonprojects.com/cable-fault-distance-finder-project/), which checks if a given line is short-ciruited with any of the other lines. The location of the fault is also calculated by a voltage divider method. I want to know if there is a method to detect an open circuit fault on the line, using just a single wire, similar to the resistance voltage divider. This should mimic a real implementation.

Comment: Since you want to detect an open, no **current can flow** making voltage detection impossible. It is however possible to detect an open (and shorts as well) using a different method. This method sends a pulse into the wire and depending on how that pulse is reflected, short/open and the distance to it can be measured.

Comment: Okay. Can you please elaborate? What do you mean by reflect?

Comment: I'm refering to a device like this: https://www.amazon.com/Fluke-Networks-DTX-1800-Cable-Analyzer/dp/B00ATQWN5A They're not cheap ! Reflect means: a pulse is send into the cable. The cable has certain properties, its characteristic impedance is an important one. If that ch. imp. changes at a certain point in the cable, the pulse will partly **reflect back**. It is similar to waves in a water reflecting against an object floating in the water. For more info, Google: 
 "transmission lines" Basically **any** cable is a transmission line so the theory always applies.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I was looking for something relatively simple to make as a mini project.

Comment: Unfortunately the reflection way is not easy to implement. That is why those testers are expensive.

Comment: With a long enough test cable, you may be able to visually see effects with an everyday oscilloscope.  If you are trying to do a "science fair" type project, using the USB/Ethernet/GPIB/Serial interface to read the captured data out of one for analysis might work.

Comment: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/build-your-own-time-domain-reflectometer/